# Hide ' > ' in the UITableView Cell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, cell, segue

[image]

When I added a action segue(push) to the cell of the table view, the thing you see in the picture appeared in the right end of the cell.
How can I hide this?

Comment: Is cell.accessoryType is set to UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator or UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this out

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
```

Hope it helps!